# How to send an SMS using the power button through an Android application running in the background?

Tags: java, android, sms, send, background-process

I have a simple android application that sends an SMS to a specified number when user presses a button. The application does not show the SMS in the standard compose view and sends it in the background. Currently the application sends SMS to an Emulator. My question is how can i accomplish the same task using the power button. I want the application to send the SMS if the user presses the power button twice. I have a slight idea of how to achieve it buy using a sms service and broadcast service but don't know how to execute it. Please provide a piece of code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             Button btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
              btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
              {
                 public void onClick(View v)
                 {
                     sendSMS("5554", "Asad here!");

                               /*here i can send message to emulator 5556. */

                  }
              });
           }
          //---sends an SMS message to another device---

           private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
           {
               SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
               sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
            }

        }
```